# Does multiplication by the split-complex number $j$ have a geometric interpretation?

Tags: complex-numbers, hyperbolic-geometry, split-complex-numbers

For complex numbers it's fairly intuitive. i² corresponds to a nice counter-clockwise rotation along the unit circle.

[rotation1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NFN2.gif)

[rotation2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtqMe.gif)

A "rotation" in the split-complex plane however corresponds to a movement alongside the "[unit-hyperbola(s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Dth.png)". This is equivalent to a [squeeze-mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTQTP.gif).

[rotation3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgYjr.gif)

As you can see there's no hyperbola on which $j$ rotates elements that leads from j to +1. What does this mean?
**How can we understand why j² is 1?**

Comment: I'm not sure you can really prove this; it's by definition of split complex numbers! How are you defining them?

Comment: It holds by definition.

Comment: You have no idea who downvoted. It certainly wasn't me. Not everyone agrees with MSE's current downvote culture. Respect from all involved is important

Comment: It's a commutative ring Cs = {a+bj | a, b ∈ R} where j² = 1. Maybe you could approach it through hyperbolic angles? But I don't know how.

Comment: I think OP is looking for a transformation of the plane that is isomorphic to the transformation $x\mapsto jx$ in the split-complex numbers. We would expect this transformation to have order 2, just as $x\mapsto ix$ has order 4. This seems to me to be a very reasonable question.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but it's too long. Multiplication by $j$ corresponds to reflecting points across the diagonal (the $y = x$ line) of the plane; $j \cdot (x + j y) = y + j x$.

Here's a relationship between multiplication and rotation. A null-basis for the split-complex numbers is given by $u = \frac{1 - j}{2}$ and $\bar{u} = \frac{1 + j}{2}$. For $z = z^u u + z^{\bar{u}} \bar{u}$ and $w = w^u u + w^{\bar{u}} \bar{u}$, $z\cdot w = z^u w^u u + z^{\bar{u}} w^{\bar{u}} \bar{u}$; i.e., the split complex numbers are isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. Since $\cosh \theta + j \sinh \theta  = e^{-\theta} u + e^{\theta} \bar{u}$, one finds $(\cosh \theta + j \sinh \theta) \cdot (\cosh \phi + j \sinh \phi) = \cosh(\theta + \phi) + j \sinh(\theta + \phi)$.

Comment: *"Multiplication by  corresponds to flipping across the diagonal"*. That's the transpose. Wait, I'm confused now, how did we go from rank reduction of A to a transpose?

Comment: I edited the post to make it clearer. The purpose of the first sentence is to explain that the split complex number 
 does not correspond to a "rotation" in the same way that the complex number 
 does. The "rotational" aspect of the split complex numbers corresponds to the second part, and you can see that $j$ is not of the form $\cosh \theta + j \sinh \theta$, so it is not one of these "rotational" elements.